# pandas groupby last n

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

What is the best way to get the mean of the last n instances using pandas groupby?

For example I have a dataframe like this:

```
frame = pd.DataFrame({'Student' : ['Bob', 'Bill', 'Bob', 'Bob', 'Bill', 'Joe', 'Joe', 'Bill', 'Bob', 'Joe'],                                      
                          'Score' : np.random.random(10)})
```

how do I get the mean of the last 3 scores for each student.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Maybe something like this?

```
>>> df.groupby("Student")["Score"].apply(lambda x: x.iloc[-3:].mean())
Student
Bill       0.513128
Bob        0.342806
Joe        0.469662
Name: Score, dtype: float64
```

You can access the last three (or fewer) elements using `.iloc[-3:]`, and then take the mean using `.mean()`.

Alternatively, you could use `.tail(3)` instead, or do it in two passes:

```
>>> df.groupby("Student").tail(3).groupby("Student")["Score"].mean()
Student
Bill       0.513128
Bob        0.342806
Joe        0.469662
Name: Score, dtype: float64
```

Comment: I suspect 2nd approach is going to be a lot faster for a big set